# Return Attribute Value of List Item with Active Class

Tags: jquery

I have a selection list and each item contains attributes. I'd like to return the attribute value on the active list item and am receiving the error "cannot read property 'value' of null".

The list:

```
<div id="selections" class="available_selections">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a id="variant_option" price="19.99" product_id="5004"  optionid="foo" class="" onclick="javascript:someFunctions(...);" onmouseout="javascript:moreFunctions(...);">
      Foo
      <input type="hidden" id="li_variant_foo" value="19.99">
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a id="variant_option" price="29.99" product_id="5004"  optionid="bar" class="active" onclick="javascript:someFunctions(...);" onmouseout="javascript:moreFunctions(...);">
      Bar
      <input type="hidden" id="li_variant_bar" value="29.99">
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a id="variant_option" price="39.99" product_id="5004"  optionid="baz" class="" onclick="javascript:someFunctions(...);" onmouseout="javascript:moreFunctions(...);">
      Baz
      <input type="hidden" id="li_variant_baz" value="39.99">
    </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'd like to return `price`, `product_id`, `optionid`, and the `id` of the hidden input and its value on the active item (our "selection").

I've tried variations of the following, using the one attribute for testing:

```
var test = $('#variant_option .active').attr('optionid');
var test2 = $('#variant_option :focus').attr('optionid');
var test3 = $('a .active').attr('optionid');
var test4 = $('a#variant_option .active').value;
var test5 = $('#variant_option').activeElement;
```

The error is always: `Cannot read property 'value' of null`.

It's something small, obvious, a snake that'll kill me - I'm sure. Plz halp.

Comment: You can use each id value only ***once*** on the whole page.

Comment: You know why do we have id (not just in html) in real life too. Why do we have an id column in a db table? Why do we assign ids to student in a classroom instead of name? why do he have id cards? Ans: to make it unique so that we know the exact person or things. Just imagine having 2 people with the same id. There will be all kind of issues. Same goes with browser so always have a unique id

Comment: This is a terribly basic question to ask, realized after the fact. Thank you for the gentle reminders!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use each `id` value only **once** on the whole page.

`id` is short for *identifier* and that means it **must be unique**, otherwise your HTML is invalid.

If you have duplicate `id` values on your page, trying to select them will always only **find the first one**.

There's many more errors in your code:

- Having an `input` element inside an `<a>` tag is not allowed.
- `price`, `product_id`, `optionid` are not valid attributes on a link. Use `data-`-prefixed attributes instead.
- You're trying to select the link and reading it's `value` - but a link does not have a `value` property.
- If you want to select a link with class `.active` you cannot have a space between `a` and `.active` - space is a selector on its own, it's called **descendant selector**.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and thoroughness in answering!